# why "while(Scanner.hasNext())" causes OutOfMemoryError in java?

Tags: java, jvm

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Main {
    public static void problem1 () {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            int n = scanner.nextInt();
            int[][] nums = new int[n][2];
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                nums[i][0] = scanner.nextInt();
                nums[i][1] = scanner.nextInt();
            }
            Arrays.sort(nums, (a, b) -> {
                return a[0] - b[0];
            });
            int[] dp = new int[n];
            Arrays.fill(dp, 1);
            int res = 1;
            for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                    if (nums[i][1] >= nums[j][1]) {
                        dp[i] = Math.max(dp[i], dp[j] + 1);
                    }
                }
                if (dp[i] > res)
                    res = dp[i];
            }
            System.out.println(res);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        problem1();
    }
}
```

[enter link description here](https://www.nowcoder.com/practice/55371b74b2f243e3820e57ee4c7b5504?tpId=182&&tqId=34448&rp=1&ru=/ta/exam-all&qru=/ta/exam-all/question-ranking)

While coding the above-mentioned code, I found that `while(scanner.hasNext())` will cause `"OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space"`while the input data is more than 1000000; And the bug can be solved by removing while loop; but in my limited experience with JVM, I don't know why; Any ideas?

Comment: Linking to some Chinese language website is not helpful.  Please provide an English translation of what it says (as text, in the Question) or remove it.

Comment: Do not vandalize your posts. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) for as long as it sees fit to do so. For alternatives to deletion, see: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 2):

We really need to see the input to be sure *why* this is failing.  But if you are getting an OOME in `hasNext()`, what is happening is that your application's input includes a token that is monstrously long.

The `hasNext()` call is going to read ahead on the input stream from the current position until it encounters a character (or EOF) that indicates the end of the next token.  The characters that are read ahead need to be buffered in memory.  The OOME means that you have managed to fill up the heap while buffering characters.

A possible "quick and dirty" workaround would be to make the heap size big enough to buffer the entire input.  **But I don't think that will work.**

Why?

Suppose you manage to buffer a monstrously big token so that `hasNext()` can return `true`.  The next thing that you do is to call `nextInt()` to read a value for `n`.  But that is most likely going to fail, because either the token (found by `hasNext()`) is not a number, or is too large a number to be returned as an `int`.  So `nextInt()` will throw an exception.

The real way to solve this is to figure out what the monstrous token actually is.  That entails looking at the input that your application is reading.

---

> And the bug can be solved by removing while loop;

Hmmm.

I read that as meaning that the OOME goes away if you remove the outer loop.  You haven't actually solved the problem.  Now your code will only process a single dataset.

Comment: thanks for your comment, and sorry for my embarrassed question, because, I found that the reason for OOM is incorrect input, and there is nothing about scanner.hasNext(), it just for a too large number initializing integer array.

Answer (score 0):

You should do `scanner.hasNextInt()` before calling `scanner.nextInt()`. Not sure why you get OOM but this may help.

Comment: thanks for your comment, and sorry for my embarrassed question, because, I found that the reason for OOM is just incorrect input, and there is nothing about scanner.hasNext(), it just for a too large number initializing integer array.